# Why doesn't CSS place exactly n squares into a div container?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a data-box in `CSS`. But when I tried to place 5 `input` squares that each is 30x30 pixel into the container `div` that is 150x150px,but it doesn't fit completely to the container. 4 of them are placed and the last one is placed into just below. I can't find why it happens. How can I fix this problem?

```css
.box-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.machine-box {
  color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
</div>
```

Comment: Or also [HTML input element wider than Containing Div](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1633522/1529630) or [Text input with 100% width inside a td expands/continues outside the td](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7525675/1529630)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property. By default, it is set to `content-box`. `width: 20%;` on the `.machine-box` doesn't include the borders, margins, and paddings on the input element.

If you apply `box-sizing: border-box;` on the `.machine-box`, borders, margins, and paddings will be part of that `width: 20%` and they'll fit nicely.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.container{
    width:500px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
}
.job-box{
    width: 150px;
    height: 170px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.job-title{
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.box-container{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.machine-box{
    color: darkgreen;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    float :left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="job-box">
        <div class="job-title">J1</div>
        <div class="box-container">
            <input type="text" class="machine-box">
            <input type="text" class="machine-box">
            <input type="text" class="machine-box">
            <input type="text" class="machine-box">
            <input type="text" class="machine-box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `width` sets the width of the content area, so it does not include borders nor paddings.

Use `box-sizing: border-box` to change this behavior.

```css
.box-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.machine-box {
  color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
  <input type="text" class="machine-box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the border. I added `box-sizing:border-box;` to your input boxes. Check the result here:

https://jsfiddle.net/4hd9v6t1/

By default, `input` elements have a border. You can either remove it or make it stay inside the element's size, by using `box-sizing:border-box;`.

Here's more info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp